# US Visa Validity for travel from India

Tags: visas, usa, indian-citizens

I intent  to travel  to  US  from India  in the last  week of September 2016  for  20 days and  have valid  US visa till November 2016. Will this visa be acceptable ?

Answer (score 3):

You should be ok. US visa [validity](https://travel.state.gov/content/visas/en/general/visa-expiration-date.html) works a bit differently than you'd expect, the expiry date is the last day you can travel to the US and the duration of stay is determined at the border by the immigration official.

Here's what the State Department has to say (emphasis mine)

> **What the Visa Expiration Date Means**
> The visa validity is the length of time you are permitted to *travel to a port-of-entry* in the United States.
> A visa [...] can be used from the date it is issued until the date it expires to travel to a U.S. port-of-entry. [...] the visa expiration date shown on your visa does not reflect how long you are authorized to stay within the United States.
>
> **Admission to the United States and your Duration of Stay**
> Upon arriving at a port of entry, the CBP official will determine the length of your visit

Comment: Question: "..travel to a U.S. port of entry one time". So if this visa has already been used, can it be used a second time?

Comment: @simonatrcl I misquoted, sorry. It can be used again if you have a multiple entry visa, and once for single entry

Comment: I thought it might be. It was just a clarification. Thanks!